# characteristic of finite commutative local rings

Tags: ring-theory

If $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ is a finite local ring then $|R| = p^{nr}$ for unique prime $p$ and $n,r \in \mathbb{N}$, where $R/\mathfrak{m} \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^r}$. Also $\text{char}(R) = p^k$ for some $1\leq k \leq n$. I know that if $\text{char}(R) = p^n$ then $R$ is commutative. Is the converse true? Any reference or counterexample is helpful.

$\textbf{Added:}$ The ring $\mathbb{F}_4[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle$ is local commutative, with char$(R) = 2$, and hence a counter example.

The next natural question is: Can we say that $k\mid n$?

Comment: Do you have some conditions for $n$ and $r$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Such $n, r$ are unique for a finite local ring.

Comment: Then you would have $n=r$, otherwise you can just interchange $n$ and $r$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I don't think you have read the full description of where the $r$ and the $n$ come from. Given the ring, it is easy to see how to get each of them, and clearly there are rings where they are not equal.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I read the full description. The question has just been edited after (due to?) my comment.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ahh, I didn't notice the timing there.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven The edit was indeed due to your comment. However, the edit was done only to avid further questions in comments, and not because it was ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I'm curious : how doyou prove the first sentence of the question ? If the proof is too long to fit a comment, could you perhaps provide a reference ?

Comment: @Max See "Finite associative rings" - by Raghavendran.